# Clicking on images with PyGame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am currently developing a game using Python and PyGame. I have made image sprites for the main option buttons, but I cannot seem to figure out how to make the images clickable which will take me to a different screen. Source code:

```
import os
import sys
import pygame
import time

class Colors:
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    dark_red = (102, 0, 0)
    grey = (128, 128, 128)
    dark_grey = (51, 51, 51)

class Variables:
    screen_w = 1000
    screen_h = 600
    battleButton = pygame.image.load("Images/battle_button.png")
    shopButton = pygame.image.load("Images/shop_button.png")
    saveButton = pygame.image.load("Images/save_button.png")
    equippedItem = pygame.image.load("Images/equipped.png")
    creditsButton = pygame.image.load("Images/credits_button.png")
    baseballBat = pygame.image.load("Images/baseball_bat.png")
    baseballBat = pygame.transform.scale(baseballBat, (250, 250))
    playerHealthMax = 100
    playerHealthMin = 0
    playerHealth = playerHealthMax
    playerCash = 0
    pygame.font.init()
    gameFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Tweaky", 70)
    title = gameFont.render("Causatum", 1, (Colors.black))
    mainFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 50)
    equippedWeap = mainFont.render("Equipped", 1, (Colors.black))
    cash = mainFont.render("Cash: ${}".format(playerCash), 1, 
(Colors.black))
    health = mainFont.render("Health: {}".format(playerHealth), 1, 
(Colors.black))
    gameVersion = mainFont.render("v1.0.0", 1, (Colors.black))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Variables.screen_w, Variables.screen_h))
pygame.display.set_caption("Causatum")
screen.fill(Colors.black)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill(Colors.grey)
    screen.blit(Variables.battleButton, (0, 170))
    screen.blit(Variables.shopButton, (0, 240))
    screen.blit(Variables.saveButton, (0, 310))
    screen.blit(Variables.title, (330, 0))
    screen.blit(Variables.equippedItem, (645, 250))
    screen.blit(Variables.baseballBat, (735, 230))
    screen.blit(Variables.equippedWeap, (723, 215))
    screen.blit(Variables.creditsButton, (0, 380))
    screen.blit(Variables.cash, (0, 50))
    screen.blit(Variables.health, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(Variables.gameVersion, (905, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#in 'Variables' add this line
battleButton_rect = battleButton.get_rect(centerx = 0, centery = 170)

#new function, outside any classes
def collide(mouseX, mouseY, rect): #new function for checking the collision of the mouse with a button
    return (mouseX >= rect.x-rect.width/2 and mouseX <= rect.x+rect.width/2 and mouseY >= rect.y-rect.height/2 and mouseY <= rect.y+rect.height/2)

# in 'while running'
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]: #0 for left button, 1 for right, 2 for middle
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if collide(mouse_pos[0], mouse_pos[1], Variables.battleButton_rect):
        #code for battle button clicked here

#replace
screen.blit(Variables.battleButton, (0, 170))
#with
screen.blit(Variables.battleButton, Variables.battleButton_rect)
```

This, of course, is only for the battle button. You need to add a Rect for every button you use. Also, I would suggest making a button class with the collision function inside and having an array of those buttons that you can iterate through without convoluting your code. But the above is a quick and dirty solution.

Hope this helps!